# Derivation in Stalnaker's letter to van Fraassen

Tags: philosophy-of-language

In Stalnaker's letter to van Fraassen, he claims the following:

[image]

Where the referenced assumptions are:

```
 (1) Stalnaker's thesis: if P(A) > 0 then P(A -> B) = P(B | A)

 (5) that the conditional satisfies Stalnaker's logic C2 [see here][2]

 (6) for any probability function there are at most two disjoint propositions with nonzero probability
```

Can someone explain how (8) is a theorem of C2? I can prove it using import-export in addition to C2 but not in C2 alone. I don't think it relies on assumptions (1) or (the denial of) (6).